# Cant get Ubuntu server to configure network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-18.04, media-server

Coming from Ubuntu server 16.04 I flashed my server and put 18 on it and didn’t realize they changed the way networking happens on the server. I have been using ifupdown forever now Ubuntu is now using netplan I have tried to get the config file made up but every time I run netplan try it says error has occurred on the line of the interface eno1. any help would be appreciated. I’d love to go back to ifupdown but can’t because i can’t get the network connected. Also every time I run a ping it’s failing to get the ip from dns but still shows on startup how many packages can be updated.

This is how I have my config file written

```
network:
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
         eno1:
        addresses: []
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
        version: 2
```

I am editing the file I found in /etc/netplan
It is named 50-cloud-init.yaml

Answer (score 0):

YAML is really sensitive to indentation and the block you posted has wrong indentation. Be careful not to mix tabs and spaces in indentation.

Also the empty address block might cause problems.

Here is a fixed config using 4 spaces as indentation:

```yaml
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
```